# Prevent Visual Studio from reformatting my ODBC SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2010, odbc

When designing a SQL statement through Visual Studio 2010 connecting to a ODBC Oracle database, at time of execution, the editor will severely reformat my query. Usually this is just an annoyance (and makes the statement much harder to read and understand) but sometimes it does nonsensical things and breaks the code completely. Can this be turned off so that my SQL statements are executed AS WRITTEN?

Here is an example. This is the statement that I enter in before execution.

```
SELECT     AC.*, STP.* FROM ME_DWH.WC_ALL_COMMENTS AC,   
(SELECT DISTINCT WC_NUMBER, SERIAL_NUMBER, ME_PART_NUMBER, planning_priority, work_number, 
 operation_step, task_type, me_type,scheduling_status, labor_hours
  FROM me_dwh.wc_standards_template_part) STP
```

This is what it becomes at time of execution. Predictably, it throws an error "AC.ME_PART_NUMBER: Invalid identifier" because its adding a nonsensical identifier "AC" where it does not belong.

```
SELECT AC.*, STP.* FROM ME_DWH.WC_ALL_COMMENTS AC,
(SELECT DISTINCT AC.WC_NUMBER, AC.SERIAL_NUMBER, AC.ME_PART_NUMBER, 
planning_priority, work_number, operation_step, task_type, me_type, 
scheduling_status, labor_hours FROM me_dwh.wc_standards_template_part) STP
```

Is there a way around this AND/OR a different ODBC SQL editor I can use?

Comment: I'd find one that doesn't let you write `SELECT *`... ;)

Comment: SQL Developer may be a better tool for the job at hand.

Comment: Well, I don't normally use SELECT * but it made the sample code easier to read.

Comment: The above query works fine with SQL Developer. Thanks for the suggestion.